# If $Y = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, how do I express $Var(\frac{1}{n}Y)$ as a function of $Var(X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

To give more context, we have $X_i = 1$ if true, $0$ otherwise. The probability that the outcome will be true is 0.6. The sample is independent. This is my work so far, but I feel like it's wrong.$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$

$\Var(\frac{1}{n}Y) = E[(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i)^2] - E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i]^2$
$ = E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i] - (E[X])^2 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = \Var(X).$

Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:
To get these equivilances, I'm using the linearity of the expected value and the fact that $E[AB] = E[A]E[B]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i)^2] - E[\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i]^2$

Up to here it is OK. Then you cannot say that $E[(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i)^2]=E[\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i]E\cdot[\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i]$. It is just $\frac1{n^2} E(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i)^2)$.

And $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i]^2=\frac1{n^2}\cdot E[\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i]^2$.

So in total we have $\frac1{n^2}\cdot Var(Y)$. We know that $Var(\frac1n\cdot Y)=Var(\overline X)=\frac{Var(X_i)}{n}$ if $X_i$ are identical and independent distributed. Thus $\frac1{n^2}\cdot Var(Y)=\frac{Var(X_i)}{n}=p\cdot (1-p)=0.6\cdot 0.4=0.24$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that clears things up. However, I'm still confused as to how we get to $Var(\overline{X}) = \frac{Var(X_i}{n}$ (I'm not farmiliar with the overline notation - what does it mean?) Thanks!

Comment: This is the variance of $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^nX_i=\overline X$ or the variance of the mean of $n$ i.i.d random variables.

Comment: I see. However, I'm still confused as to how we get this equivalence. Because, in the end, I simply proved that $Var(aX) =  a^2Var(X)$, right?

Comment: This is not true in your case (very important). You have n independent random variables. In your case you add the variances. $Var(\sum X_i)=Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+\ldots+Var(X_n)=n\cdot Var(X)$. You see there is no $n^2$.

Comment: Ah, so this is one of the mistakes I made? But now how do I go on to show that $Var(\frac{1}{n}Y) = \frac{1}{n}Var(X_i)?$

Comment: It is $\frac1n Y= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Look at the definition from the beginning. And we have $Var(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=\frac1{n^2}\cdot  Var( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=\frac1{n^2}\cdot  n\cdot Var(X_i)$

Answer (score 3):

For independent RV's one has
$$ Var(\sum_1^n X_i) = \sum_1^n Var(X_i)$$
hence
$$ Var(\frac1n Y) =\frac1{n^2} n Var(X_1)=\frac1n Var(X_1) $$
since $X_i$'s are identically distributed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm confused as to how $\sum$ becomes an $n$? We never went over the property you used in class, so I'm not sure that I'm allowed to use it. The paper does ask to first find $E[Y]$ and $E[\frac{1}{n}Y]$. Maybe it's supposed to be a hint? Thanks again.

Comment: The left term in the second row of your eqn is wrong. It should be $$ E [\frac1n  \sum_iX_i \frac1n \sum_j X_j]$$

Comment: Since they're independent, can't I split them up into a product of expected values? Also, why am I getting $E[X]^2$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}E[X]^2 ?$

Comment: $\sum_ i X_i \sum_j X_j = \sum_{i\neq j} X_iX_j + \sum_ i X_i^2$ now calculate the expectation